# How to pass command line arguments to Wix Burn Upgrade

Tags: wix, upgrade, bootstrapper

I have a Wix Bootstrapper which conditionally installs various components, which are defaulted to not install unless a command line parameter is sent. This works fine on the initial install, but when I attempt to perform an upgrade, the command line parameters do not seem to be being read.

```
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i001: Burn v3.9.526.0, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{be649f4c-6ffd-49d3-a3c8-8afd4204cb47}\CW6Installer.exe, cmdline: '-uninstall -quiet -burn.related.upgrade -burn.ancestors={717281ba-5728-475a-b875-28bd3845630a} -burn.embedded BurnPipe.{C82D65E7-7381-4B4C-878D-568115066990} {66F62C30-1C12-430C-906C-AC38DFB24EEF} 12292 -burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{158F71C5-4458-44CA-8B92-A6DB7D6BAA3F} {2F432B3C-DE4A-40FD-B18E-36D8A9C9A703} 888'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i003: This bundle is being run by a related bundle as type 'Upgrade'.
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLCW6' to value '0'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLSQL' to value '0'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLMSMQ' to value '0'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLCRYSTAL' to value '0'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'ORC' to value '0'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'JOBS' to value '0'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'ROUTE' to value '0'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'ACTG' to value '1'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'DONOTMSMQ' to value '0'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing string variable 'CUSTCODE' to value 'DSDE'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing string variable 'SERVER' to value 'DellServer'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing string variable 'DBNAME' to value 'DSDETRAN'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'USEINTEGRATEDSECURITY' to value '0'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'APPENDWILDCARD' to value '0'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing string variable 'INSTALLFOLDER' to value 'C:\'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing string variable 'UPDATEDATE' to value '04/01/1991'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing string variable 'INSTALLTYPE' to value 'update'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Initializing string variable 'LaunchTarget' to value '[INSTALLFOLDER]\PD6\EXE\CW6.exe'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:47]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\nickd\AppData\Local\Temp\CompuWeigh_20140625102047.log'
[1614:12E4][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '6.0.4.0'
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i100: Detect begin, 5 packages
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i102: Detected related bundle: {717281ba-5728-475a-b875-28bd3845630a}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 6.0.5.0, operation: None
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i103: Detected related package: {70D98F12-F7B1-4E37-8335-872C1B059C70}, scope: PerMachine, version: 6.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: Downgrade
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i101: Detected package: MessageQueuing, state: Absent, cached: None
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i101: Detected package: CrystalRuntime2011, state: Present, cached: Complete
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i101: Detected package: SQLSERVER64, state: Absent, cached: None
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i101: Detected package: SQLSERVER32, state: Absent, cached: None
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i101: Detected package: Compuweigh, state: Obsolete, cached: None
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i052: Condition 'VersionNT > v5.2' evaluates to true.
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i200: Plan begin, 5 packages, action: Uninstall
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i214: Plan skipped related bundle: {717281ba-5728-475a-b875-28bd3845630a}, type: Upgrade, because it was previously scheduled.
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: SQLSERVER32
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: SQLSERVER64
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i207: Planned related bundle: {717281ba-5728-475a-b875-28bd3845630a}, type: Upgrade, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, dependency: None
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i201: Planned package: Compuweigh, state: Obsolete, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Unregister
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i201: Planned package: SQLSERVER32, state: Absent, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i201: Planned package: SQLSERVER64, state: Absent, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i201: Planned package: CrystalRuntime2011, state: Present, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Unregister
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i201: Planned package: MessageQueuing, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Unregister
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i300: Apply begin
[0378:2FEC][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i326: Removed dependency: {be649f4c-6ffd-49d3-a3c8-8afd4204cb47} on package provider: {FBAB5DC0-657B-424F-BE58-07DEFF68917C}, package CrystalRuntime2011
[0378:2FEC][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {FBAB5DC0-657B-424F-BE58-07DEFF68917C}, package: CrystalRuntime2011
[0378:2FEC][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {B6BF9BEA-9E42-47C4-B5A4-EC9CC4CDA8B3}, package: MessageQueuing
[0378:2FEC][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {be649f4c-6ffd-49d3-a3c8-8afd4204cb47}
[0378:2FEC][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i352: Removing cached bundle: {be649f4c-6ffd-49d3-a3c8-8afd4204cb47}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{be649f4c-6ffd-49d3-a3c8-8afd4204cb47}\
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i000: The prerequisites were already installed. The bootstrapper application will not be reloaded to prevent an infinite loop.
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: ACTG = 1
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: APPENDWILDCARD = 0
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: CUSTCODE = DSDE
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: DBNAME = DSDETRAN
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: DONOTMSMQ = 0
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: INSTALLCRYSTAL = 0
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: INSTALLCW6 = 0
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: INSTALLFOLDER = C:\
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: INSTALLMSMQ = 0
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: INSTALLSQL = 0
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: INSTALLTYPE = update
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: JOBS = 0
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: LaunchTarget = C:\\PD6\EXE\CW6.exe
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: ORC = 0
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: ROUTE = 0
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: SERVER = DellServer
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: UPDATEDATE = 04/01/1991
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: USEINTEGRATEDSECURITY = 0
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: VersionNT = 6.3.0.0
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 3
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: WixBundleFileVersion = 6.0.4.0
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 1
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\nickd\AppData\Local\Temp\CompuWeigh_20140625102047.log
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Paradigm Software LLC
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = CompuWeigh
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\Users\nickd\Desktop\WixTestingInstall\CW6\CW6Installer.exe
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = C:\Users\nickd\Desktop\WixTestingInstall\CW6\
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {be649f4c-6ffd-49d3-a3c8-8afd4204cb47}
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 6.0.4.0
[1614:2434][2014-06-25T10:20:48]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

The code above is the log file for the "Upgrade" which didn't work. I am attempting to upgrade the Compuweigh package. I am passing the parameter INSTALLCW6=1 to the package, which is the condition to run the MSI, but to no avail. None of my command line parameters are passing through. Please help!

Comment: This was probably fixed by this [pull request](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/pull/86), which will be in the next build.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there, by chance, an ETA on the next build?

Comment: http://wixtoolset.org/releases/v3-9-702-0/

Comment: I have updated my version of wix but this issue is still occurring. When I try and upgrade, the bootstrapper progress text will say "Previous Version" and perform the RemoveFiles function, but will not install the new files for the new version, leaving only files created by custom actions in the install folder.

Comment: The log doesn't match what you're saying.  The log shows the bundle uninstalling without INSTALLCW6=1 on the command line.  From your description, I would expect to see the bundle installing with INSTALLCW6=1 on the command line.

Comment: I just attempted to force the install by hard coding it so that the variable INSTALLCW6 initializes to 1 if nothing is passed. The progress bar still displays "Previous Version" Then does not install the package. The command line parameters are still not being passed. DO I need to specify anything such as /upgrade in command line for these to get passed on upgrade? The command line parameters are still not being passed to the Bootstrapper. If I haven't already said, INSTALLCW6=1 Is the InstallCondition for the MSIPackage I am trying to upgrade.

Comment: Please show the log for the bundle that is installing.

Comment: {5A470353-F2AD-4744-B454-3A29D110A5DD} 11988'
[2F64:3A04][2014-07-03T16:25:46]i003: This bundle is being run by a related bundle as type 'Upgrade'.
[2F64:3A04][2014-07-03T16:25:46]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLCW6' to value '1'
[2F64:3A04][2014-07-03T16:25:46]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLSQL' to value '0'
[2F64:3A04][2014-07-03T16:25:46]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLMSMQ' to value '0'
[2F64:3A04][2014-07-03T16:25:46]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLCRYSTAL' to value '0'

Comment: This issue only seems to happen when "This bundle is being run by a related bundle as type 'Upgrade'."

Comment: That's not the right log, that is from the old bundle that is being uninstalled.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QDf83juiMDUU1tdG9EdkUxMUk/edit?usp=sharing                 This is the log created for the "install" of the msi which only seems to remove. As I stated previously, the command line parameters still don't seem to be being passed though.

Comment: "This bundle is being run by a related bundle" means that this is a log of a bundle that was "kicked off" by another bundle.  I'm asking for the log of the original bundle, not any MSI logs.  The log in your question shows the bundle uninstalling.  Burn will never install a package if the bundle is uninstalling.

Comment: If you mean the bundle I ran, which should then run the MSI to upgrade it, what i posted on July 3 was a part of that. Here is the full file:   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QDf83juiMDRFlnV2p0ZEVRYlE/edit?usp=sharing                   the two files I have shared links for are the only two log files created by my attempt to update.

Comment: I give up.  Maybe someone on wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net can help you.

Comment: Alright, thank you anyway for your time and help.